# tlmgr updating from outdated mirror

Tags: installing, updating, tlmgr

I sometimes run into a problem with updating with tlmgr if the mirror that is automatically selected is behind compared to the mirror from which the previous update was done (if I wait for a package update to fix a certain I'm suffering from bug I sometimes update a several times a day).

Updating package works fine, the newer package versions from the previous update are kept, but if the previous update installed a new package, the new update will remove the package again and even repeating the update with another server which is up-to-date will skip the new package as "forcefully removed"

I know that I can reinstall forcefully removed packages, but can this problem somehow be avoided to happen in the first place? Can one somehow check if the automatically selected mirror is at least as up-to-date than the mirror from the previous update? Or can one make tlmgr choose always the newest mirror?

Comment: Have you seen http://dante.ctan.org/mirmon/ ?

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, I have, but how does this help with the automatic selection of tlmgr? Can you please elaborate on your idea?

Comment: I never had the case that an update removed a newer local package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It happens whenever the package was newly added in the previous update. I had this problem at least 3 times already